# Should I disclose I'm the creator of software/code in an answer in which I recommend it as the solution?

Tags: discussion

If I'm answering a question in which code or a piece of software me or my company has written can successfully answer the user's question, should I disclose that in the answer?

I'm not talking about quick, one sentence answers which state:

> If you use My Software Product™, all your problems will magically go away.

Obviously, an answer like that would be consider spam/link-only and be deleted.

What I mean are full-fledged answers that attempt to answer all the OP's question(s), possibly with code examples, using said software/code.

For example:

> You can use My Software Product™ to achieve what you're asking. To do that, utilize the `myAwesomeMethod()` with the serialized string.
>
> You can also chain methods if you need to do more of the things with the stuff.
>
> `var awesome = require('awesome-module');
>   var results = awesome.myAwesomeMethod().anotherNeatMethod();`
>
> Disclosure: I work for the Neato Company who creates My Software Product™.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes. If for no other reason than transparency. Though consider that it will _also_ look better in the off chance that you end up answering a handful of questions and mentioning that product- It looks much less like product placement. (By the way, I don't suggest doing that, but I'm sure you knew that already.)

Comment: I want to write a library where the methods are actually called `myAwesomeMethod` and `anotherNeatMethod`.

Comment: Actually, looking at it, this is [already answered in the help center:](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers." (Emphasis original.)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: I hated e.g. [Ira Baxter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter) for doing such frequently. Meanwhile, he left some disclaimer in his profile. You should take care of those answers, they may easily get flagged as being spam.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is mentioned *twice* in the help center, and can be found by searching ["disclose"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=disclose) on the help center search.

From the [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page:

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

The same exact text, with slightly different emphasis, is the *first paragraph* of ["How to not be a spammer."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

So not only *should* you disclose your affiliation, according to the help center, you *must* disclose it.